# JPA ManyToOne relationship - Can't insert row with foreign key

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

In my Spring Boot project I have two models, **Building** and **Location**. I'm trying to create a new **Location** which belongs to a **Building**.

These are my models:

**Location model**

```
public class Location implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter
    private Integer id;
    
    @NonNull
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String name;

    @NonNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "building_id")
    @JsonBackReference("building-location")
    @ToString.Exclude
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Building building;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Version
    @Column(name = "lock_version")
    private Integer lockVersion;
}
```

**Building model**

```
public class Building implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter
    private Integer id;
    
    @NonNull
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "building")
    @JsonManagedReference("building-location")
    @ToString.Exclude
    @Getter
    private List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Version
    @Column(name = "lock_version")
    private Integer lockVersion;

}
```

This is my controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Response> createLocation(@Valid @RequestBody Location location) {
    Location createdLocation = locationRepository.save(location);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(
            new Response(ResponseTypeEnum.Success, createdLocation)
    );
}
```

This is the request body:

```
{
    "name": "Kitchen",
    "building": {
        "id": 9
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that JPA is not recognizing the **Building** object, so when I try to save the **Location** I get the following exception:

`SQLException Column 'building_id' cannot be null. Query is: insert into location (building_id, lock_version, name) values (?, ?, ?), parameters [<null>,0,'Yoga Room']`.

If I get the building from DB using `findById` and then set the **Building** property in the **Location** object it would work, but I don't want to fetch the object in order to save a Location instance. I just want to pass the foreign key and save the new instance.

Can I do that with JPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that in JPA but one of the alternative solutions, if you do not want to hit the database for the Building entity, would be to load a reference instead:

```
Building b = buildingRepository.getOne(buildingId);
location.setBuilding(b);
Location createdLocation = locationRepository.save(location);
```

Remember that all needs to be within the same transaction.

`getOne` javadoc:

> Returns a reference to the entity with the given identifier.

Comment: Thanks @Maciej. Even though this will be within a transaction it feels like a limitation, having to get the reference first in order to create a new object. If I had several relations in this object, I would end up fetching all its references first so I can create it. It's too much much code just to reference to foreign keys.
**Is there any pattern or good practice to make this look more elegant?** I'm planning to work with DTO's to make a validation layer between my model and the data exposed to the client.

Comment: You could bypass the entities and go for the DTO's straight away but only when you query for the data. During persiting you need to use entites and manage them within the persistence context.

Answer (score 0):

The Exception claims about a null `'building_id'`, which means that the `id` of the passed `building` object is `null` or wasn't correctly set.

And that's because when you try to `save` the `Location` instance, JPA will try to set the `building` property from your request, so it needs to set the `id` but it couldn't do that **because you haven't defined a `setter` method for the `id`** in your `Building` entity.

You need to change your code to add the setter method with your lombok annotation:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Getter
@Setter
private Integer id;
```

Comment: I added the `@Setter` annotation and I still get the same exception. It seems like JPA is never mapping the `building_id` column with the object `Building`. Do you have any code, example or reference which I can test in order to reproduce the wanted behavior?

Comment: @DanielCastillo I don't see why it shouldn't be working with `@Setter`, your posted `data` structure seems to be correct, otherwise you can go for a `dto` but you will need to hit the database to get the `building` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add buildingId field in class Location

```
public class Location implements Serializable {

    ... 

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "building_id")
    @JsonProperty("building_id")
    private Integer buildingId;

    ...
}
```

Then you can send request with body

```
{
    "name": "Kitchen",
    "building_id": 9
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Trần Quốc Vũ. This would effectively work but I would have to set the properties `insertable = false` and `updatable = false` in my `Building` field, which would make it useless when I'm trying to fetch the Location object. I want to be able to send just the `buildingId` foreign key and create a `Location` object without having to fetch the Building first. Your approach would do that but would not fetch the Building object when fetching the Location.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is the following:

```
package com.deportes.deportes_api.tablas;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@Entity
@Table(name="disciplina")
public class Disciplina {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Version
    private Integer version;
    @Pattern(regexp = ".*([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}$)",message="El nombre debe contener letras y     numeros con una longitud mínima de 2 caracteres")
    private String nombre;

    @Pattern(regexp = "([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})",message="El código debe tener 10 caracteres")
    @Column(name="codigo", unique=true)
    private String codigo;

    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updatedAt;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="deporte_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Deporte deporte; 

    @Column(name = "deporte_id")
    @JsonProperty("deporte_id")
    private Integer deporte_id;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }
    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }
    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }
    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }
    public void setUpdatedAt(Date date) {
        this.updatedAt = date;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite late but may help someone.

What you have to do to fix this issue is to include another field in your class containing the building id, but you mark it as *non insertable* and *non updatable*.

Then during saving you use that id to fetch the building and pass it to the location before saving. Enough talk, let's move to the demonstration.

```
public class Building implements Serializable {
...
@Column(name = "building_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer buildingId; 
...
}
```

Then in the post request:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Response> createLocation(@Valid @RequestBody Location location) {
    Building building = buildingRepository.findById(location.getBuildingId());
    location.setBuilding(building);
    Location createdLocation = locationRepository.save(location);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(
            new Response(ResponseTypeEnum.Success, createdLocation)
    );
}
```